# Unable to read lines using multithread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to read and print the lines in a csv file.I need to use multi threading for the same.There are 10 lines in the file,if I provide 2 threads(no of threads is  user input dependent) it should read all the 10 lines,where each line should be read and printed once by any of the thread.

But I am unable to successfully execute it.If I provide 2 threads,it will read 2 lines(random lines),doesn't read the remaining  and terminate the program. 
I am trying to write the code for it.

**main class:**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ThreadMain implements Runnable {

    String name;
    static Map<Integer, Boolean> map = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

    public synchronized static Map<Integer, Boolean> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public synchronized static void setMap(Map<Integer, Boolean> map) {
        ThreadMain.map = map;
    }

    public ThreadMain(String s) {
        name = s;
    }

    public void run() {
        ThreadReader.Reader(name);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = null;
        boolean repeat = false;
        int threads;

        do {
            try {
                scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Enter no. of threads: ");
                threads = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

                // Initializing map
                int i;
                for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                    map.put(i, false);
                }

                ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
                for (i = 1; i <= threads; i++) {
                    executor.execute(new ThreadMain("Thread #" + "is "+i));
                    System.out.println("Started Thread: " + i);
                }

                executor.shutdown();
                while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
                }
                try {
                   executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error in terminating threads...");
                }
                // System.out.println(finished);

                // Printing key-value pairs
                // Set set = map.entrySet();
                Set set = ThreadMain.getMap().entrySet();
                Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry mentry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
                    System.out.print("Key: " + mentry.getKey()  );
                    System.out.println(" & Value: "+mentry.getValue());
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                repeat = true;
                System.out.println("Invalid number format...");
                System.out.println("");
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                repeat = true;
                System.out.println("Invalid input format...");
                System.out.println("");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error...");
                // e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (repeat);

        scan.close();
    }

}
```

**file read(runnable class):**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Random;

public class ThreadReader {

    public static void Reader(String threadName) {

       // ThreadReaderCheck check = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = null;
        Random rand;
        int randomInt;
        boolean generate;
        int i;

        try {
            //check = new ThreadReaderCheck();
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ThreadCSV.csv"));
                synchronized (br) {
                    // Generating random number
                    generate = false;
                    rand = new Random();

                    do {
                        randomInt = rand.nextInt(11);

                        if (randomInt == 0) {
                            generate = true;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println(threadName + " " + randomInt);
                            if (randomInt > 0 && randomInt < 11) {
                                line = br.readLine();
                                System.out.println(threadName + " " + ThreadMain.map.get(randomInt));
                                if (ThreadMain.map.get(randomInt) == false) {
                                    for (i = 1; i < randomInt; i++) {
                                        line = br.readLine();
                                    }
                                    if (line != null) {
                                        ThreadMain.map.put(randomInt, true);
                                        System.out.println(threadName + " " + line);
                                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                                        br.notifyAll();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    generate = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } while (generate);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in reading from file...");
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error while closing file...");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why? This is madness. Use a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build a thread 'lock' so that once a thread is completed, it can finish writing even if the next thread is ready. You can use 'wait' and 'notify' to build this. Insert the code before using print / println to check if the thread is ready and send all other threads the 'wait' signal. This will result in the threads no longer colliding and keep the code output clean.

A great online resource that will help learn to build this into your code is available at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjMTaVykOpc

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Could you please explain the  thread lock with respect to the above program.